# rails devise active admin add user from dashboard for different user mdel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I am trying to to add User model inside active admin module. Here I am using Devise gem for my user registration. Here my user table and admin users are different

I have created an active admin resource called users.rb and inside that I want to add or edit password of users but it is saving them in plain text. This is my active admin resource users.rb:

```
   ActiveAdmin.register User do
  # See permitted parameters documentation:
  # https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
  #
   # permit_params :email, :encrypted_password, :remember_created_at, :sign_in_count, :current_sign_in_at, :avatar
   index do
     selectable_column
     id_column
     column :email
     column :current_sign_in_at
     column :sign_in_count
     column :created_at
     actions
   end

   filter :email
   filter :current_sign_in_at
   filter :sign_in_count
   filter :created_at

   show do
       attributes_table do
         row :email
         row :current_sign_in_at
         row :image
       end

     end

   form do |f|
     f.inputs do
       f.input :email
       f.input :password
       f.input :password_confirmation
     end
     f.actions
   end

  end
```

How can I add devise users and edit them from active admin dashboard here password is saving in plain text where do I need to make changes.

Comment: do you have in user.rb model something like this?   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

Comment: I have user.rb under model folder

Comment: i'm sure you do, but is there devise command? provide the code

Comment: I just copied the admin_users.rb auto generated form inside admin/users.rb and everything is working.